# How to bind control to object property?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I've literally never used WPF before, only WinForms and I'm trying to follow [this tutorial](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/819294/WPF-MVVM-step-by-step-Basics-to-Advance-Level), but the sample code is really just terrible. Incomplete snippets and a lot is left to the reader to infer where everything belongs.

It's talking about adding data binding and compares this C# code:

> `using CustomerViewModel;`

To this XAML code:

> `xmlns:custns="clr-namespace:CustomerViewModel;assembly=CustomerViewModel"`

But nowhere does this article seem to show *where* this is supposed to go. Below that it says you don't need to actually write binding code and can instead use the UI / Property sheet in Visual Studio, but VS2010 does not look anything like those screenshots so I'm trying to do it this way.

Anyways, this is what I have in the XAML for my application's only `Window`:

```
<Window x:Class="NYMS_Rewrite.MainWindow"
  xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
  xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
  xmlns:custns="clr-namespace:NYMS_Rewrite.view_models.FormProcessorViewModel;assembly=NYMS_Rewrite.view_models.FormProcessorViewModel"
  Title="NYMS Logical Checks" Height="606" Width="525" Background="AliceBlue" DataContext="{Binding}">
```

This code does not compile, however, and is giving me this error:

> A using namespace directive can only be applied to namespaces; `NYMS_Rewrite.view_models.FormProcessorViewModel` is a type not a namespace;

If I double click the error, it takes me to `MainWindow.g.cs` (what the hell is this!? It doesn't show in my Solution Explorer)

And the first line is this `using` statement:

```
using NYMS_Rewrite.view_models.FormProcessorViewModel;
```

I've tried shortening to just `using NYMS_Rewrite.view_models;` but as soon as I compile it goes back to what it was. I *assume* this is being generated by my XAML but even if I change that to just `clr-namespace:NYMS_Rewrite.view_models;assembly=NYMS_Rewrite.view_models` I still get the same results.

And that class is defined as so:

```
namespace NYMS_Rewrite.view_models
{
    class FormProcessorViewModel
    {
        // stuff
    }
}
```

So I don't know why it thinks it's an invalid namespace. All I wanted to do is bind a few textboxes to my view model's string properties.

**EDIT** Fixed, working XAML with Abin's answer:

```
<Window x:Class="NYMS_Rewrite.MainWindow"
  xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
  xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
  xmlns:fpvm="clr-namespace:NYMS_Rewrite.view_models"
  Title="NYMS Logical Checks" Height="606" Width="525" Background="AliceBlue" DataContext="{Binding}">
    <Window.Resources>
        <fpvm:FormProcessorViewModel x:Key="fpvmObj" />
    </Window.Resources>
```

Comment: remove `xmlns:custns="clr-namespace:NYMS_Rewrite.view_models.FormProcessorViewModel;assembly=NYMS_Rewrite.view_models.FormProcessorViewModel"` from your XAML

Comment: The ".g" in MainWindow.g.cs stand for "generated"

Comment: @AbinMathew Don't I need that so that in the designer I can find a `FormProcessorViewModel` object in the `Data Binding` property / configuration tool?

Comment: Yes its needed. Now you can add your namespace by typing `xmlns:custns="You have to give your name space here. " ` a list of name space will show up for selecting it. find the one pointing your `ViewModel`

Comment: The error is because the XAML `compiler` is not able to find out the `namespace` you specified.   First you have to build your `ViewModel` Project.

Comment: @AbinMathew Thank you. If you'd like to submit those comments as answer I'll gladly vote / Accept it. Manually typing it all out, rather than copy-pasting and trying to rename things I was able to successfully bind my textbox to some of the properties in my view model object.

Comment: Glad i posted it as answer. happy learning

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is because of bad `namespace`

try removing the `xmlns:custns="clr-namespace:NYMS_Rewrite.view_models.FormProcessorViewModel;ass‌​embly=NYMS_Rewrite.view_models.FormProcessorViewModel"` From XAML and specify correct namespace which points your `ViewModel`

The error is because the `XAML compiler` is not able to find out the `namespace` you specified. First you have to build your `ViewModel` Project.

For Example `xmlns:Utility="clr-namespace:ecclient.viewer.Utility"` 
`xmlns` = `xml name space` , `Utility` is the alias name you can use in `XAML`, `clr-namespace:` says that you are referring to a name space then your name space.